# How to make page responsive only on mobile device

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have been working on a web page and finally made it responsive but how can i make it responsive for only computer, the min-computer will be a mini laptop. I have searched google for answers but still no help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need reponsive for mobile device or (for only computer, the min-computer will be a mini laptop)

Comment: Use `@media` queries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest Way to Make Website Responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917664/fastest-way-to-make-website-responsive)

Comment: Your question had been answered previously. How can you not find this on google? There are lot of resources of it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917664/fastest-way-to-make-website-responsive

Answer (score 2):

Use @media queries. To target medium screen devices use this

```
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { 
}

/* ----------- Retina Screens ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px)
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
}
```

Check here for device specific media queries:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/